# Stored procedure to execute a query and return selected values if the query returns only 1 result

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

So my query is the following, which may return many results:

```
SELECT P_CODE, NAME FROM TEST.dbo.PEOPLE
WHERE NAME LIKE '%JA%'
AND P_CODE LIKE '%003%'
AND DOB LIKE '%1958%'
AND HKID = ''
AND (MOBILE LIKE '%28%' OR TEL LIKE '%28%')
```

I would like to integrate this into a Stored Procedure (or View?) so that it will only return a result if the query results in exactly 1 row. If there's 0 or > 1, then it should return no results.

Comment: Do you want it to return an empty resultset, or not run the select at all?

Comment: It's going to return to a Django Model, so I suppose an empty result set would be the most streamlined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to return an empty resultset in cases other than 1:

```
;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT P_CODE, NAME, c = COUNT(*) OVER()
  FROM TEST.dbo.PEOPLE
  WHERE NAME LIKE '%JA%'
  AND P_CODE LIKE '%003%'
  AND DOB LIKE '%1958%'
  AND HKID = ''
  AND (MOBILE LIKE '%28%' OR TEL LIKE '%28%')
)
SELECT P_CODE, NAME FROM x WHERE c = 1;
```

Otherwise, you'll have to run the query twice (or dump the results to intermediate storage, such as a #temp table) - once to get the count, and once to decide based on the count whether to run the `SELECT` or not.

Answer (score 1):

Effectively you want something akin to FirstOrDefault() from the Linq-to-SQL implementation but done on the server-side which means you will need to execute the query in a stored procedure, dumping the results into a [temp table variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/food1635ebb-f751-4de1-8bbc-cae161f90821.aspx) and then access [@@ROWCOUNT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/foo97a47998-81d9-4331-a244-9eb8b6fe4a56.aspx) afterwards to get the number of rows that were returned and then decide whether or not to forward the results on to the caller.  <strike>If you do, be sure to use TOP 1 in the query from the temp table so that you only get a single result out as you desire.</strike>

**UPDATE:**

- I described the alternate solution from what Aaron describes in his answer (which I like better).
- Removed unnecessary TOP specifier in solution specification.

Comment: You don't need to use `TOP 1` if you are deciding, based on the number of rows in the temp table, whether to run the query. (If the count is 1, run the query; no TOP required. If the count is <> 1, don't run the query; still no TOP required.)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I'm just not quite up to speed yet this morning. ;-)

Comment: Also, you don't need to tell us what you removed in your edit (or keep it there with strikethrough). You can just remove it. If anybody is curious, they can get that information from [clicking on the edited link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20521066/revisions). It drives me crazy when people do this in code that is stored in source control. You don't need to comment out code that no longer belongs, you can just remove it. We can always get it back from version control.